# IAM policy to allow EC2 instance API access only to modify itself

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I'm trying to set up an app that configures my instances upon launch and I want to close down that app's API access as much as possible. My current policy is as follows:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1388183890000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:AssociateAddress",
        "ec2:CreateTags",
        "ec2:DescribeInstances",
        "ec2:RebootInstances"
      ],
      "Resource":"*"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, this allows the app to perform any of these actions on anything in EC2. Is there a way I can lock down the actions of the app on an ec2 instance to either that specific instance, or to all of the boxes that have the same IAM role?

Comment: Check this solution if you want to restrict instance to working on itself only without using tags: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56924928/401499

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. You need to first assign some relevant and common tags to the EC2 instances in question. And then restrict the IAM policy access only to those instances using `ec2:ResourceTag/tag-key`.

Check [this example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-policies-for-amazon-ec2.html#ex3):

Here is the relevant code from above example:

```
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:TerminateInstances",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:instance/*",
      "Condition": {
         "StringEquals": {
            "ec2:ResourceTag/purpose": "test"
         }
      }
   }
```

This way, you can restrict the access to only those instances which have necessary tags.

Read more about Tagging [here](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2010/09/new-amazon-ec2-feature-resource-tagging.html). Hope this helps.

Comment: This works for regular instances, but not for spot instances because you [can't assign tags](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts-spot-instances-request-tags.html) to instances initiated by a spot request.

Comment: I would say you're out of luck then. Do let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: it is not working for me. i cannot filter the instances based on tags please help

Comment: This is a bit old but you can now assign tags to spot instances:

`aws ec2 create-tags --resources <spot-instance-id> --tags Key=<key>,Value=<value>`

Answer (score 1):

For the instance to read its own tags you will also need the describe tags permission.

```
"ec2:DescribeTags"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aws:userid` and `ec2:InstanceID` in the condition element:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateTags",
        "ec2:RebootInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:userid": "*:${ec2:InstanceID}"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["ec2:DescribeInstances"],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

**NOTE!** Not all EC2 actions support resource-level permissions, that's why policies granting such access must specify `"*"` in the resource element.
For example, most of the `ec2:Describe*` actions will work only when `Resource: "*"`.

Unfortunately, `ec2:AssociateAddress` does not support this condition.

Comment: Looks to me like this policy does not restrict access to just the instance itself.