# AWS IAM EC2 policy limited to originating instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I'm working on a setup where I need to terminate AWS instances because of inactivity (i.e. nothing new in web-server access logs since a period of time). Those instances are testing instances and are created automatically by CI/CD software.

I would like those instances to identify themselves that they become abandoned and terminate themselves. I want to assign a generic iam-role to each of them that will only allow the instance the termination of itself and not the peer instances.

So far I've been here:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ExamplePolicies_EC2.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html#policy-vars-wheretouse
- https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/4gglxk/iam_policy_to_allow_ec2_instance_to_only_query/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_iam_mfa-selfmanage.html

And figured out that there are 2 variables available in policies:

```
ec2-instance-id
ec2:SourceInstanceARN
```

I came up with few variations of my role policy but none of them work:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:TerminateInstances",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "ArnEquals": {
                    "ec2:SourceInstanceARN": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/${ec2-instance-id}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:TerminateInstances",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/${ec2-instance-id}"
        }
    ]
}
```

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:TerminateInstances",
            "Resource": "${ec2:SourceInstanceARN}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it actually possible to achieve the desired behavior, i.e. to only allow instance to perform specific operation on itself (e.g. Termination)?

**UPDATE:**
I do know that I can work with tags, that is what I'm doing meanwhile, but that means that all tagged instances can terminate their peers. That is a bit too loose restriction, I'd like to really limit it to the instance it

[AWS IAM: Allow EC2 instance to stop itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39018803/aws-iam-allow-ec2-instance-to-stop-itself?rq=1)
[IAM policy to allow EC2 instance API access only to modify itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864429/iam-policy-to-allow-ec2-instance-api-access-only-to-modify-itself?rq=1)

Comment: If terminating itself is your only concern, launch the instance with [`InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/terminating-instances.html#Using_ChangingInstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior) set to `Terminate` and just have the code on the machine run `/sbin/poweroff` as root.  When the EC2 infrastructure sees the instance try to power itself off, the instance will be terminated, exactly as if you sent an API request to terminate it.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Great idea! Can also run `sudo shutdown now -h`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You were close with your `condition`. The trick is to compare instance ARN with `ec2:sourceInstanceARN`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:DeleteTags",
                "ec2:DescribeTags",
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ARN": "${ec2:SourceInstanceARN}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Clearly for testing purposes I allowed my instances with this policy to tag and stop themselves.

Comment: works, consider also posting your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39018803/aws-iam-allow-ec2-instance-to-stop-itself?rq=1 and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864429/iam-policy-to-allow-ec2-instance-api-access-only-to-modify-itself?rq=1

Comment: How did you get it to work @AntonBoritskiy? What command did you run? When I try `aws ec2 describe-tags --filters Name=resource-id,Values=<instance id>` it still gets denied.

Comment: we run it like this 
```
aws ec2 terminate-instances --instance-ids $(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id/ 2>/dev/null) --region $(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone 2>/dev/null | sed 's/.$//')
```

Comment: @AntonBoritskiy it seems that some actions such as {Terminate,Stop}Instances do work with this condition, but not others such as DescribeTags. I can't seem to get a group of tagged instances to "only describe their tags".

Comment: @petobens Consider the fact that you are trying to get a list of instances and then run describe tags on returned result while this policy enables actions on single instance only. You might require `ec2:DescribeInstances` (or some other) to do that.

Comment: Hello @TomaszKapłoński 
Any idea why it might not work for this case: 
`{ "Version": "2012-10-17", "Statement": [ { "Sid": "VisualEditor0", "Effect": "Allow", "Action": [ "ec2:ModifyInstanceMetadataOptions" ], "Resource": "*", "Condition": { "StringEquals": { "aws:SourceArn": "${ec2:SourceInstanceARN}" }}}]}`
(aws:ARN seems to have been superseded by aws:SourceArn)

Comment: This does not work anymore - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access-analyzer-reference-policy-checks.html#access-analyzer-reference-policy-checks-error-unsupported-global-condition-key

Comment: same, confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

Since the "aws:ARN" condition no longer works, I have found the following approach to work for instances launched with an IAM role:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Allow instance to modify itself",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:DeleteTags",
        "ec2:CreateTags"
        ],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:userid": "*:${ec2:InstanceID}"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `aws:userid` and `ec2:InstanceID` in the condition element:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:RebootInstances",
                "ec2:StopInstances",
                "ec2:TerminateInstances"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:userid": "*:${ec2:InstanceID}"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": ["ec2:DescribeInstances"],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**NOTE!** Not all EC2 actions support resource-level permissions, that's why policies granting such access must specify `"*"` in the resource element.
For example, most of the `ec2:Describe*` actions will work only when `Resource: "*"`.

Comment: I'll give a try when I get back to that automatic-termination script and post an update here