# AWS IAM Roles: Policy with permissions only over the instance itself and not every resource

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I'll try to explain my issue the best I can.

I want to create an IAM Role with my own RebootPolicy that, when attached to an EC2 instance, allows that instance to reboot itself (but only itself). Currently the only thing I can do is create a role with a policy that allows Reboot in all instances.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RebootInstances",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I know I could technically add the specific id of the instance to the policy, but the idea is that I use the policy in any instance I want and not just an specific one. I tried following the documentation at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonec2.html but I don't know how to implement it.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not just use `sudo reboot`? No API calls required!

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I think `reboot` is slightly different from restarting from API. For example, `reboot` won't change ephemeral IP, but restarting from API will.

Comment: Restarting via API call will _not_ change IP or lose Instance Store.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Ah, thanks for pointing me out! I was wrong. Stopping and starting will change the IP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can self reference EC2 by using `ec2:SourceInstanceARN` IAM policy variable.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RebootInstances",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ARN": "${ec2:SourceInstanceARN}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Ooh, that's nice! Also shown here: [AWS IAM EC2 policy limited to originating instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56924928/174777)

Comment: Thanks! That was precisely what I was looking for. I was trying to solve it just using the "Resource" attribute but it seems we need the "Condition" the way you used it. The weird thing was that when creating the policy, I got this warning from the AWS Console: "This policy does not grant any permissions. To grant access, policies must have an action that has an applicable resource or condition. For details, choose Show remaining". Still the policy worked for me

Comment: @jbbb The warnings are sometimes stupid. Just ignore them. I'm glad it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use: `$(aws:userid)`

[IAM Policy Elements: Variables and Tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html) says:

> `aws:userid` will be set to `role-id:ec2-instance-id` where `role-id` is the unique id of the role and the `ec2-instance-id` is the unique identifier of the EC2 instance.